# shell script to run on boot on Mac OS X does not run all commands

Tags: bash, shell, boot, osx, docker

On OS X, I am trying to use [lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) to run a shell script upon booting.  I have a file ~/desktop/_admin/boot/bootdocker.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
boot2docker up
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.177.59.103:2475
```

My problem is that if I run the script from the command line with any of these:

```
$bash bootdocker.sh
$./bootdocker.sh
$sh bootdocker.sh
```

They run the first command, but do not run the second command exporting the DOCKER_HOST variable.

Can anyone see the error I'm making?

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want to set `$DOCKER_HOST` for all your shells that you spawn, then you'll need to incorporate it into your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

**NOTE:** What you're attempting to do will never work since child processes cannot augment their parent's environments.

You can do this using `boot2docker` like so:

```
$ eval $(boot2docker shellinit)
```

The `shellinit` verb to `boot2docker` is new in v1.2.0, and is meant for setting the `$DOCKER_HOST`. When you run it bare it produces the following output:

```
$ boot2docker shellinit
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375
```

Answer (score 0):

The second command is executed correctly, but since the script is running in a subshell (child process), the parent shell to which you return after the execution does not inherit the env var.

Answer (score 0):

to get var `$DOCKER_HOST` you sould run

. ./bootdocker.sh

That is

- `.` a dot which mean "use the file as if typed"
- `./bootdocker.sh` file is to be search localy.